# Чтение файла с разным типом данных, записанных в файл

Tags: c++, текст

Суть вопроса:

Имеется файл, записанный в формате 2 байта, 1 байт, 1 байт. Значения в файле всегда положительным (то есть unsigned) и записаны последовательно в одну строку. Требуется провести чтение файла и записать их в вектор. Как это можно реализовать?

Перепробовал уже множество способов, но так и не могу понять, как его корректно прочитать (и структурой пытался, и через переменные, и тд и тп, просто не понимаю свою проблему).

Чтение осуществлял через ifstream, но можно любой вариант использовать. Сам файл представлен в формате txt или dat.

Файл можно представить в виде такой последовательности
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так файл бинарный? Или текстовый, с этими 7dc4 и иже с ним?...

Comment: Файл бинарный, но точно известно, что он структурирован по определённому правилу. Как раз тут то условие, что два байта на первую переменную, и по одному байту на две следующие переменные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уж решили читать байты, то надо стиснуть зубы и читать байты.

Байт в C++ - символ без знака. Можно читать просто символы, дальнейшая обработка будет осложнена.

Код ниже сразу читает одну запись в буфер. Затем из байтов конструируются значения. Так сделано потому что читать сразу в `unsigned short` плохая идея.

```
// так делать не надо!
unsigned short v1;
ifs.read(reinterpet_cast<char *>(&v1), 2);
```

- `unsigned short` может оказаться длиннее двух байт. Тогда будет неопределённое поведение - в переменной останется мусор.
- [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) внутри `unsigned short` может быть разным. На разных машинах ваш код прочтет разные значения.
- если вас беспокоит производительность, то чтение из файла куда медленнее битовых операций при конструировании значений.
- если вы уверены что порядок байтов под контролем и не хотите ничего считать, то читайте прямо в `uint16_t`. У него размер ровно два байта - ни больше, ни меньше. Но я вас предупредил. (*В комментарии указывают что этот способ опирается на размер байта в восемь бит, а он может отличаться. Ещё одна причина так не делать.*)

Код:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs("record", std::ios::binary);

    unsigned char buffer[4];
    // читайте запись целиком, так проще обработать ошибки, так быстрее
    // тут нужно приведение, зато дальше будет проще работать
    if (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer), sizeof buffer)) {
        // конструируем значение из байтов - защита от различного
        // порядка байтов на разных компьютерах
        unsigned short v1 = buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << CHAR_BIT);
        unsigned char v2 = buffer[2];
        unsigned char v3 = buffer[3];
        std::cout << v1 << ' '
                  << static_cast<int>(v2) << ' '
                  << static_cast<int>(v3) << '\n';
    } else {
        // всегда контролируйте успешность чтения!
        // не перечесть сколько возникает ошибок из-за чтения после конца файла
        std::cerr << "Error reading record\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `читайте прямо в uint16_t. У него размер ровно два байта` А если `CHAR_BIT == 16`?

Comment: C `CHAR_BIT != 8` невозможно читать файлы переносимым образом. В частности POSIX фиксирует размер байта (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631491/why-did-posix-mandate-char-bit-8). Но вы правы в том смысле, что я срезал угол. Но если его не срезать, то написать правильно работающую программу становиться очень трудно. И в защиту себя скажу что я способ с `uint16_t` не рекомендовал.

Comment: Раз уж речь зашла о порядке байт (*big-endian* (он же network byte order) / *little-endian*), то стоит параметризовать его и для файла.

Comment: Да, приблизительно такое же написал пару недель назад, и из-за отъезда не мог ответить на вопрос. Спасибо, ваш ответ более чем верен.

Отдельно уточню, что научный руководитель согласился с тем кодом, который я ему представил и он более чем соответствует вашему.

Последнее, что добавлю, это то, что в Notepad++ было неверное чтение символов (байтового представления) из файла. Использовал Listener из TotalCommander и представление файла было совершенно другим. Так что ещё добавлю, что стоит использовать соответствующие инструменты для чтения таких файлов. Спасибо за ваш ответ!

Answer (score 2):

В комментарий не влезу...
В чем проблема?

```
unsigned short var1;
unsigned char var2, var3;

ifstream in("....",ios::binary);

for(;;)
{
    in.read((char*)&var1,2);
    in.read((char*)&var2,1);
    in.read((char*)&var3,1);
    ....
}
```

Структура — ну, нужна ее корректная упаковка, на байт.

Что тут не так?

Comment: ну ну. ifstream  имеет имя `i`, а в коде используется `in`. Потом прибежит анонимный минусатор и скажет - а где проверка ошибок:)

Comment: @KoVadim Но так я по крайней мере буду знать, почему минусы :)

Comment: но я разочарую - наш минусатор полный профан в с++. просто полный ноль:)

Comment: `unsigned short` может быть длиннее двух байт. Лучше использовать `uint16_t`.

Comment: На машинах с разным `endianness` код будет давать разные результаты. Лучше читать в массив из двух байт и из него арифметикой конструировать значение `unsigned short`.